# Haskell Boolean Function implementation

Tags: haskell, boolean, existential-type

I am trying to solve following problem -- given all selectors(e^i_n) and some boolean functions(`{f_1, f_2, f_n}`) enumerate all functions of n arguments in closure(in [f_1,f_2,..f_n]).

So, I implement BooleanFunctionClass and existencial BooleanFunction type. 
Are they aganist spirit of Haskell?

```
class BooleanFunctionClass a where
  arity :: a -> Int

instance BooleanFunctionClass Bool where
  arity _ = 0

instance BooleanFunctionClass a => BooleanFunctionClass (Bool -> a) where
    arity f =  arity  (f True) + 1

data BooleanFunction = forall  a. (BooleanFunctionClass a) => BooleanFunction a String
instance Show BooleanFunction where
  show (BooleanFunction _ str) = show str
```

But I have no idea how implement selector(function of n arguments, that returns k-th).
I want `selector :: Int -> Int -> BooleanFunction`. Any suggestions?

PS. Sorry. I do not know, how insert TeX in Markdown.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just model boolean functions as `BooleanFunction { arity :: Int, f :: [Bool] -> Bool }`.

Comment: I will try this approach, but it is not math styled.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want it to do?

Comment: One problem with this is that I don't think you can't write `apply :: BooleanFunction -> Bool -> ... -> Bool -> Bool`; you can't know how many `Bool`s to fill in to the `...`s!  You might be able to write `applyToList :: BooleanFunction -> [Bool] -> Bool`, but that would fail dynamically, and so you'd just effectively be using a more complex version of Sjoerd Visscher's suggested approach (which is probably the right one).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if you want the arity to be checked at compile time, lists probably aren't going to do the job (as you suggested in the comments).

You'll need tuples, or something like it. The nicest way to deal with variable sized tuples is Template Haskell. Also [TupleTH](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tuple-th/0.2.4/doc/html/TupleTH.html) has already done a lot of the work for you regarding processing tuples in a type safe way.

Comment: No. Tuples do not work, as I will not be able to partly apply.
I wanted to avoid TH, but seems that hope is lost.